# Difference between two long tails and two short tails

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

In the picture above, does this pdf have two long tails or two short tails?

Comment: I take it those points on the flanks are zero.  If so, short tails.  Going to zero in a finite range is as short as you can get.

Comment: If this is a density curve for a distribution taking values in $(0, 1),$ then it seems it is a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha = \beta = 2.$ See Wikipedia on 'beta distribution' if you are interested in that.